# How to have 2 Listviews with each taking 50% and one starting empty and increasing in size.

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I need to have 2 Listviews in a vertical LinearLayout with each occupying 50% of the screen. I achieved this by setting the Listview's weight 50 0.5 each.

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/searchResultSelection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:divider="@null"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/searchResultList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the top Listview starts empty while the bottom one usually occupies the entire screen. What i want is for the bottom to start at 100% and every time and item is added to the top added, the top will increase while the bottom will decrease until the top one reaches an height of 50%.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/searchResultSelection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/dummy"
            android:divider="@null"
             />

        <View 
            android:id="@+id/dummy"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/searchResultList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchResultSelection"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```